# What is the distribution of the natural numbers in the list of the sum of their digits taken in binary representation?

Tags: statistics, binary

I'm wondering what is the distribution of the numbers in the list of the sum of their digits in base $2$. To be clear on what I mean is that if you take the $n$ first natural numbers (without zero), and if you write their representation in binary and if you make the sum of their digits in the binary represention, how much $1$, $2$, $3$, et ceatera, will you find in this list?

And because I don't really know how to explain with words what i'm asking, to be precise, i'm looking for the distribution of the value of the $f$ function defines such as,

$$f(n)=\sum_{i=0}^{{\lfloor\log_2(n)\rfloor}+1} a_i(\overline{n}^2)$$

Where $\overline{n}^2$ is the binary representation of $n$.

---

So it looks, using a little program in Python $3.0$, that the distribution is a normal distribution but I don't really know how can I prove I'm in the truth or not. Because I'd like to know what is the exact distribution when $n goes to the infinity.

```
import math

def somme_des_nombres(liste):                   
    n=len(liste)                    
    S=0
    k=0
    while k<n:
        S=S+int(liste[k])
        k=k+1
    return S

def ff(n):
    d=[]
    e=[]
    for s in range(1,n+1):
        d.append(sum(map(int,list(bin(s)[2:]))))
    return d

def compte(liste):
    n=len(liste)
    p=math.floor(math.log(n,2))+1
    a=[]
    for s in range(1,p+1):
        a.append(liste[0:].count(s))
    return a
```

---

For $n=1.000.000$

```
from pylab import *

x = array([20, 190, 1140, 4845, 15503, 38741, 77367, 125250, 165740, 179892, 160042, 116140, 68091, 31754, 11500, 3116, 594, 71, 4, 0])
y = array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20])
plot(y, x)
```

The graph i found is this one [image: distribution]

Can you help me? Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inadvertently, you have asked more than one question.  I will only answer the question "if you take the n first natural numbers (without zero), and if you write their representation in binary and if you make the sum of their digits in the binary represention, how much 1, 2, 3, et ceatera, will you find in this list? " which is what you meant to ask anyway.

Fix $n= 2^k-1$ so I don't have to bother with logarithms (I'll let you work out the rest of the cases by taking appropriate logarithms and floors).  You want the distribution of *frequencies* of sums of binary digits in the integer range $[1,n]$ (that is what 'how many' means).

Now each $l\in [1,n]$ can be represented uniquely as a $k$-bit string, and the sum of binary digits equals the number of $1$'s in the digital expansion.  Thus, for each sum $s \in [1,k]$, you want to find the number of $l\in [1,n]$ with exactly $s$ number of ones.

It is an easy exercise to show that the number of $k$-bit strings with $s$ ones is $\binom{k}{s}$ (choose an $s$-element subset of $[k]$ and that uniquely determines your assignment of ones).  So when you plot pairs ((# of ones),(# of strings with this number of ones)) you get $(s,\binom{k}{s})$ as you found experimentally.  This is the binomial distribution, and appropriately renormalized, it tends to the normal distribution as $k\to \infty$ by the De Moivre - Laplace theorem.

Comment: Chemistry is what i'm studying, math is my hobby. Thank's for your answer, things are easier for me now.